# How to order results by customer expression in Hibernate/HQL/JPQL

Tags: hibernate, sql-order-by, hql, jpql

I have persistent entity Cats (id, name). I want to query all cats (using HQL/JPQL) that cats named 'Tom' were in top, i.e. order by custom expression name='Tom'.

In Oracle I can do so using

```
ORDER BY CASE name WHEN 'Tom' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END.
```

How to do in Hibernate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just written a test class and the following works in Hibernate/JPA 3.6.1:

```
SELECT o 
  FROM Cat o 
 ORDER BY CASE o.name WHEN 'Tom' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: Works fine with Hibernate 4.0.4 and PostgreSQL. I can even add additional `order by` columns.

Answer (score 0):

The same query is not possible in plain JPQL/HQL, but there are two ways to get the same result

1) Write a native query and map it to the entity Cat.

2) Create a view and subclass the entity Cat to map to the view.

I'm quite aware that none of the solutions are ideal, but neither Hibernate nor JPA have a feature for this scenario, apart from the native query. I think is up to you to think what is the best of these three solutions, as this will impact your integration tests.